# Minimum coin change: reconstruct solution from this algorithm

Tags: python-2.7, dynamic-programming

I have implemented the dynamic programming [solution](http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/csor4231.F07/dynamic.pdf) for the classic minimum coin change [puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) in Python and am very happy with my short and easy to understand (to me) solution:

```
def memoize(fcn):
    cache = {}
    def decorated(d, p):
        if p not in cache:
            cache[p] = fcn(d, p)
        return cache[p]
    return decorated

@memoize
def mc(d, p):
    if p in d: return 1
    cands = [n for n in d if n < p]
    if not cands: return 10**20
    return 1 + min ([mc(d, p-d_i) for d_i in cands])

In [101]:
d = [1, 5, 10, 25, 21]
p = 63
mc(d, p)
Out[101]:
3
```

But now I thought I would try and actually back out the coins used in the optimal solution. I.e. for the above case I would want to output 21 + 21 + 21.

However, with my program formulation I see no way of easily doing that. I would have to keep track of the entire solution tree, and then recursively move up nodes according to the change that was subtracted in order to get to that particular node.

So, is there an easy way to modify my solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Please use more descriptive variable names. What's `d`? What's `p`? Also note that you're only using `p` to memoize, which might be affecting something.

Comment: I added the input/output example to make the variable names obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def memoize(fcn, cache = {}):
    def decorated(d, p):
        if p not in cache:
            cache[p] = fcn(d, p)
        return cache[p]
    return decorated

@memoize
def mc(d, p):
    if p in d:
        return (1, [p])

    cands = [n for n in d if n < p]

    if not cands:
        return (10**20, [])

    d_i, pair = min(
        [(d_i, mc(d, p-d_i)) for d_i in cands],
        key=lambda e: e[1][0]
    )

    return (1 + pair[0], pair[1] + [d_i])
```

In your example, it will return a pair (3, [21, 21, 21]).

That was a quick solution. If you need to integrate or distribute it I would recommend you use OOP style, like this:

```
class MinimumCoinChangeSolver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.coins = None
        self.count = None
        self.__cache = {}


    def solve(self, coins, amount):
        self.reset_cache()
        self.coins = self.__recursive_solve(coins, amount)
        self.count = len(self.coins)


    def reset_cache(self):
        self.__cache = {}


    def __recursive_solve(self, coins, amount):
        # try to find solution in cache
        if amount in self.__cache:
            solution = self.__cache[amount]

        else:
            # if given amount equals to one of teh coins, return list which contains corresponding coin (it equals to amount)
            if amount in coins:
                solution = [amount]

            else:
                # find coins candidates, they are less then given amount
                coins_cands = filter(
                    lambda coin: coin < amount,
                    coins
                )

                # if there is no coins candidate, return no coins (it is an empty list on coins)
                if not coins_cands:
                    solution = []

                else:
                    # try to use every coin among the candidates, and recursively find list of coins in every case
                    solutions = map(
                        lambda coin: self.__recursive_solve(coins, amount - coin),
                        coins_cands
                    )

                    # ignoring empty solutions
                    solutions = filter(
                        lambda sol: bool(sol),
                        solutions
                    )

                    # if there is no non-empty solutons, return empty list
                    if not solutions:
                        solution = []

                    else:
                        # choose the solution which has minimum number of coins
                        min_solution = min(
                            solutions,
                            key=lambda sol: len(sol)
                        )

                        # remember corresponding coin
                        coin = amount - sum(min_solution)

                        # solution
                        solution = min_solution + [coin]

        # save solution in cache
        self.__cache[amount] = solution

        # return
        return solution



if __name__ == "__main__":
    solver = MinimumCoinChangeSolver()
    solver.solve([1, 5, 10, 25, 21], 63)
    print solver.coins
    print solver.count
```

Comment: I also noticed I can get some strange results if I call my mc function several times in a row, because the memoization cache isn't cleared after each function call. Do you have a quick tip for solving that as well? Thanks again

Comment: I have edited memoize function to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't seem to work. If declare cache outside of the memoize function and write cache={} before each function call, it works. But that is not a very pretty fix

Comment: And I am trying to understand you solution, I would never have come up with something like that. Very nice I think. If you have time it would be nice if you added some of your thought process in stepping trough the program... Thanks